# what is the equivalent option for displaying a notificationbox in chrome extension like in firefox addon

Tags: notifications, google-chrome-extension, browser-addons

I am developing extensions for a site for major three browsers (FF,Chrome,IE).
I started with firefox and now working with chrome.
I want to know how to implement an option like the firefox xul notificationbox https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XUL:notificationbox in chrome?

How to display the do you want to save password panel in chrome like in firefox notificationbox?

I inspected LastPass and found that they are injecting a div inside the body tag as the first child of the body tag. is that the way it has to be ? or some other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an experimental API for this: [`chrome.experimental.infobars`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.infobars.html).

Until it gets stable creating your own div is the only option.